# put a logo on sportsfloor adobe software

Tags: adobe

I try to put a logo in a video but I want it to be on the floor where people walk over it.
With blending it is still on the person so how can I best act in this way. Does anybody knows a good tutorial or can easily explain what I have to do?

The sporter in the video will run over the logo. from several angles.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you provide some further details ie: are you using greenscreen, what software you have access to, is this a live event, pre-filmed, etc as your question is very broad and not really a direct question

Comment: sorry i shot video on a tournament and we want our logo on the sportsfloor so we have a slow motion video. and a .png file with a black and white logo.
I have an Adobe CC available and now we try to put the png into the video. With After Effects i can angle the png to the right way but now when a player cross it the png will be on the player instead of the player blocking the logo.

Hope this explains more what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If video was made without any preliminary preparation, you most probably shall use [rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping). You can see tutorial for After Effects [here](https://youtu.be/fsJX7zJSMU0).

However, if floor is monocolored and it will not blend with any leg parts, you can try to separate its part for the logo, and use keying on it. But most probably it will be messy.

Comment: pretty much what my answer would have been lots and lots of rotoscoping